# Timeouts crashing publisher

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ I have a service that consumes messages of a queue and then downloads pages based on those messages and publishing another message on a different queue that is eventually consumed and stored in a database. But I'm having trouble with one particular source that is slow and causing everything to come crashing down.

The way the consumer works is that it will grab several messages off the queue (prefetch count is currently 50) and fires off threads to do the downloads. So I have a function that looks something like this (note this could be running on multiple threads at once):

```
private void ReceivedHandler(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
{
      var message = CrawledJobInfo.Deserialize(ea.Body);
      try
      {
           _downloaders.Download(message);   // this is the part that can take some time
           if (queueIsDead)
           {
               return;
           }
           var body = message.Serialize();
           var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
           properties.Persistent = true;

           channel.BasicPublish(exchange: directExchange,
                                routingKey: queueName,
                                basicProperties: properties,
                                body: body);

           channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
       }
}
```

This works fine most of the time, but with the one download source that takes a long time, I get an exception like this:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: A connection 
attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.IO.BufferedStream.Flush() 
at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Flush() at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.WriteFrameSet(IList`1 frames) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.Command.TransmitAsFrameSet(Int32 channelNumber, Connection connection) at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.Command.Transmit(Int32 channelNumber, Connection connection) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SessionBase.Transmit(Command cmd) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelSend(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model._Private_BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.AutorecoveringModel.BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body) 
at JobDownloadLibrary.JobDownloadQueue.ReceivedHandler(Object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) in C:\Users\matt.burland\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Downloader\DownloadLibrary\DownloadQueue.cs:line 154
```

Which then seems to cause all the other jobs being processed to die with `RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException`

So my question is how can I avoid this? Or at the very least how can I gracefully clean up and restart so that my service will keep running? I thought it might be a problem with the heart beat, so I tried shortening it to 20 seconds, but that didn't seem to improve the situation. I also tried catching `AlreadyClosedExceptions` and using that to disconnect my received handler, make the queue as dead and have the client code create a new instance of the queue, but that seems to still leave a mess.

Looking at the rabbit logs itself, I do see memory alarms once in a while, but they appear to clear themselves almost right away:

> =WARNING REPORT==== 15-Jun-2016::10:04:27 ===
>   memory resource limit alarm set on node rabbit@CLUST01.
>
> ---
>
> *** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
>
> ---
>
> =WARNING REPORT==== 15-Jun-2016::10:04:28 ===
>   memory resource limit alarm cleared on node rabbit@CLUST01
>
> =WARNING REPORT==== 15-Jun-2016::10:04:28 ===
>   memory resource limit alarm cleared across the cluster

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late to the party. It's either connection or session that has been closed. I'm not sure if autorecovery works for channels, but as far as I know connection problems should be handled if `AutomaticRecoveryEnabled` equals true. You could subscribe to the `ModelShutdown` event which is fired when channel is destroyed and try to recreate a channel. I'd also subscribe to the `ConnectionShutdown` event which is fired when connection is destroyed. You could try to recreate channel/connection/both in case of event(s) if they are not recreated automatically by driver.

Also make sure you not sharing channels between threads/tasks. It's recommended to use one channel per thread.